# Sending Zoom action using Keyboard action not working for me in chrome

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using below code to send zoom action to chrome and it seems its not working for me.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options = options)
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page")
search_field = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("html")
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.key_down(Keys.CONTROL).key_down(Keys.ADD).key_up(Keys.ADD).key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
```

Comment: Also I tried using the below code but had no luck
    driver.execute_script(" var evt = document.createEvent('KeyboardEvent');evt.initKeyboardEvent('keypress', true, true, window,true,false, false, false,107,0);var body = document.body;body.dispatchEvent(evt);");
Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: I am having the same issue.  I am running chromedriver version 2.29.